# Ubuntu can't boot after upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 without inserting a random remote disk/harddrive

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 13.10

The problem is so weird. 
I upgraded my laptop from 13.04 to 13.10. The upgrade went smoothly and I restarted the machine as required when the upgrade finished.

After the restart, the grub menu was still shown as usual but nothing showed up after I select ubuntu as I used to. The ubuntu was NOT booted and the harddisk LED was NOT blinking neither. Only a blank screen was shown forever.

However, after I plug in any remote storage disk/harddrive into the laptop and start it, ubuntu runs. As far as I see, the only difference is in the bios boots option, there is one more entry for booting from usb with a usb disk inserted...

The problem is still there whenever I start it without a usb disk inserted...

The machine is dual-booted with windows 8 and the windows OS works fine after upgrade...

Comment: Is your USB bootable? If USB is boot-able and when you start your system while USB inserted, Ubuntu boots from your USB or from your HDD?

Comment: It boots from my HDD. I just need to insert a random storage, it boots to the installed Ubuntu..

Comment: Execute these commands once: `sudo update-grub` , `sudo update-initramfs -u`. and try to restart your system without the any removable USB. If it doesn't help then give a try to [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced pretty much the same symptoms as above. After removing the "quiet" and "splash" kernel options from the grub command line and booting Ubuntu I saw more clues and my problem seems the same as described here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+question/175746
In fact, the suggestion at the bottom of that page works for me, namely:
adding the kernel option "processor.nocst=1" to the grub command line.
Hope this helps anyone.